# Unable to click on Sub menu link after mouse hover in Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

i have to click on sub menu link, which is displayed after hovering the mouse on Main menu.

Below code work perfectly on Firefox:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("menuMainContracts"));
builder.moveToElement(we).perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement sublink = driver.findElement(By.id("mnuSubContracts"));
builder.moveToElement(sublink).click().build().perform();
```

But in Internet Explorer it does not click on sub menu link, instead it tries to click on Main menu itself.

It does not show any error message also. Please help to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two chances.

1.Your Application frontend design may restrict IE support. Can be some odd or classy framework might be used.

2.In case, if you able to perform the same in manual, then you need to have a proper approach. Try the following,

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("menuMainContracts"));
builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform(); // you have missed to build here !
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement sublink = driver.findElement(By.id("mnuSubContracts"));
builder.moveToElement(sublink).click().build().perform();
```

or

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("menuMainContracts"));
WebElement sublink = driver.findElement(By.id("mnuSubContracts"));  
builder.moveToElement(we).click().moveToElement(sublink).click().build().perform();
```

I have some other suggestions as well, try to call Excepted conditions in the middle of these advance actions.(in your case, waiting to sub menu to be appeared). But i haven't tried them. this may be technically a fatal one. try and keep the community posted on the outcomes.

Comment: Karthikeyan, this application has support to only IE. But my code works perfectly in Firefox also. I tried your first approach, by adding the build(), but it results the same. It tries to click on menu  even though i have mention click for submenu link.

Comment: @Karthikeyan, there is an inherint problem with IE driver for such kind of click action. You can find it at and navigate to Browser focues area. (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver). Simple solution is to move the mouse cursor out of the screen area.

Comment: @Vinay Totally agreed and +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to move the mouse programmatically out of the window area.

```
         final int MAX_Y = 4;
         final int MAX_X = 4 ;

        Robot robot = null;
        try
        {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e)
        {

        }
        Random random = new Random();
        robot.mouseMove(random.nextInt(MAX_X), random.nextInt(MAX_Y));
```